# Oracle Apex 19.1 advisor showing wrong errors

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

The advisor tool in Oracle Apex is a great tool to use.

The problem is that I have a big app, and I'm getting about 750 check results each time.
Some of them are not relevant, and some of them are even not true.

For example, I'm getting many errors for "... does not exist". But these items do exist.
I tried to export+import the application but the problem still occur.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for anyone in the future. One of the main recurring errors "P1XX does not exist" was because of spaces in "Items to submit" section that exists in some fields. Apparently, the advisor considers the space as part of the item name.